# Debugging in Xcode 6.2

Tags: xcode, swift, debugging

I am developing a Mac application in **Xcode** 6.2 with **Swift**.
All my global variables and enumerations are in a separate swift file `Globals.swift`. The program so far works as expected.

But I am unable to see this global variables in the debug window. On the lower left of the debug window I selected All. I see outlets, local variables, but no global variables!

What do I have to change to see them?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with Xcode since some versions.
One way is to see the global variables by issuing the below command in the right hand debugger window

(lldb) target variable *variableName* 
OR
(lldb) ta v *variableName*